# Como trazer uma aplicação para a frente(do background para foreground)?

Tags: android, android-activity

Estou finalizando um app onde a pessoa o executa mas, normalmente, ele fica minimizado, rodando em segundo plano.

A pessoa o executa, mas grande parte do tempo a pessoa pode ficar mexendo em outras coisas do celular.

Gostaria que esse app, respondendo a um determinado evento (uma resposta de um webservice, por exemplo), reapareça para o usuário, mesmo que esse usuário esteja mexendo em outros aplicativos.

Podemos dizer que esse aplicativo em determinados momentos tem prioridade máxima e precisa ser exibido ao usuário, interrompendo qualquer ação que ele esteja fazendo.

Comment: Já deu uma olhada no [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O mecanismo usado no Android para indicar ao utilizador que uma aplicação necessita da sua atenção são as [notificações](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications).

O aplicativo lança a notificação, o utilizador quando entender lê a mensagem e actua em conformidade. 
Essa é a forma aconselhada, por ser pouco invasiva.

Se de facto quer trazer a sua Activity para a frente, sem o consentimento do utilizador, use o `startActivity()`.

```
Intent it = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
it.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(it);
```